# MySQL Использовать предыдущее значение вычисляемого столбца

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно с помощью запроса SQL добавить колонку TOTAL, в которой будет прибавляться VAL_CHANGE к предыдущему расчетному значению TOTAL с порогом в 10 (не увеличивать значение сверх 10). Первым исходным TOTAL считать тоже 10.

То есть должна получиться такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать оконные функции, делать промежуточную колонку с нарастающим итогом. Больше всего не ясно, как использовать предыдущее значение вычисляемого столбца для расчета текущего значения в этом же столбце.

Запрос формирования исходной таблицы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  val_id INT,
  val_change INT
);

INSERT INTO mytable (val_id, val_change) VALUES
(1, -2),
(2, 3),
(3, -4),
(4, 5),
(5, -7),
(6, 8),
(7, -3),
(8, 2),
(9, 1),
(10, 4);
```

Comment: Выложите пример исходных как текстовые форматированные CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, ибо по фотографиям мы не лечим.

Comment: добавил запрос формирования исходной таблицы